# How long does each HTTP request add to page load time?

Tags: apache, http, httprequest

I know that pages with lots of files take longer to load, but how much longer?
How much faster would a page with 1 200kb CSS file load, compared to a page with 10 20kb CSS files, for example?
I need to know if it's worth combining javascript files into one, sacrificing easy maintenance.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You should check out build tools like gulp or grunt to combine all of your css and javascript files! This way you can keep functionality separated and still deliver a big chunk of code when using it productively.

Is it worth it? Absolutety! A colleague once held an internal presentation showing how much time the browser spent by simply sending requests and waiting for responses. Each of these requests contains a lot of overhead by establishing a connection and sending header information and that overhead becomes increasingly painful the slower your connection is.

You might want to continue reading here: https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-bundle-assets
or here: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-concat-css

Comment: This does not answer the question.